# Why is the time complexity of the brute solution of nearestPalindromic the square root of n?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, time-complexity, big-o

```
public class Solution {
    public String nearestPalindromic(String n) {
        long num = Long.parseLong(n);
        for (long i = 1;; i++) {
            if (isPalindrome(num - i))
                return "" + (num - i);
            if (isPalindrome(num + i))
                return "" + (num + i);
        }
    }
    boolean isPalindrome(long x) {
        long t = x, rev = 0;
        while (t > 0) {
            rev = 10 * rev + t % 10;
            t /= 10;
        }
        return rev == x;
    }
}
```

[Found here](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-closest-palindrome/solution/)

In the explanation of the brute force solution seen above, Leetcode claims "Up to 2 x sqrt{n}​ numbers could be generated in the worst case."

how do we know that the closest palindrome is within sqrt{n} distance of the input?

My second question is if there are 2*sqrt{n} numbers generated in the worst case then shouldn't the overall time complexity be 2*sqrt{n} * n since isPalindrome is log(n) with base 10?

Edit: 2nd question has been answered in comments.

Comment: We may consider `isPalindrome` to be `O(1)` because the number of iterations can never exceed the log of the maximum `long`, which is typically something like 20.  It's conventional to treat the sizes of fixed data types as a constant.  If this algorithm were arbitrary precision then indeed we should treat `isPalindrome(x)` as `O(log x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just figure out how many numbers say from 1 to 1,000,000 are palindromic. Say that number is n. If you examine a million consecutive numbers starting at 1, n of them are palindromic. So if you examine numbers until you find a palindromic one, you examine on average 1,000,000 / n numbers.